# unicast in Play framework and SSE (scala): how do i know which stream to send to?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, actor, server-sent-events

my app lists hosts, and the list is dynamic and changing. it is based on Akka actors and Server Sent Events.
when a new client connects, they need to get the current list to display. but, i don't want to push the list to all clients every time a new one connects. so, followed the realtime elastic search example and emulated unicast by creating an (Enumerator, Channel) per Connect() and giving it an UUID. when i need to broadcast i will map over all and update them, with the intent of being able to do unicast to clients (and there should be very few of those).

my problem is - how do i get the new client its UUID so it can use it? the flow i am looking for is:
- client asks for EventStream
- server creates a new (Enumerator, channel) with a UUID, and returns Enumerator and UUID to client
- client asks for table using uuid
- server pushes table only on channel corresponding to the uuid

so, how would the client know about the UUID? had it been web socket, sending the request should have had the desired result, as it would have reached its own channel. but in SSE the client -> server is done on a different channel. any solutions to that?

code snippets:

```
case class Connected(uuid: UUID, enumerator: Enumerator[ JsValue ] )

trait MyActor extends Actor{
  var channelMap = new HashMap[UUID,(Enumerator[JsValue], Channel[JsValue])]

  def connect() = {
    val con = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    channelMap += (uuid -> con)
    Connected(uuid, con._1)
  }
...
}

object HostsActor extends MyActor {
...
  override def receive = {
    case Connect => {
      sender ! connect
    }
...
}

object Actors {
  def hostsStream = {
    getStream(getActor("hosts", Props (HostsActor)))
  }

  def getActor(actorPath: String, actorProps : Props): Future[ActorRef] = {
    /* some regular code to create a new actor if the path does not exist, or return the existing one else */
  }


  def getStream(far: Future[ActorRef]) = {
    far flatMap {ar =>
      (ar ? Connect).mapTo[Connected].map { stream =>
        stream
      }
    }
  }
...
}

object AppController extends Controller {
  def getHostsStream = Action.async {
    Actors.hostsStream map { ac =>
************************************
**  how do i use the UUID here??  **
************************************
      Ok.feed(ac.enumerator &> EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by asynchronously pushing the uuid after returning the channel, with some time in between:

```
  override def receive = {
    case Connect => {
      val con = connect()
      sender ! con
      import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0.1 seconds){
        unicast(
          con.uuid, 
          JsObject (
            Seq (
              "uuid" -> JsString(con.uuid.toString)   
            )    
          ) 
        )
      }
    }
```

this achieved its goal - the client got the UUID and was able to cache and use it to push a getHostsList to the server:

```
  @stream = new EventSource("/streams/hosts")
  @stream.addEventListener "message", (event) =>
    data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    if data.uuid
      @uuid = data.uuid
      $.ajax
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/streams/hosts/" + @uuid + "/sendlist"
        success: (data) ->
          console.log("sent hosts request to server successfully")
        error: () ->
          console.log("failed sending hosts request to server")
    else
      ****************************
      *                          *
      *  handle parsing hosts    *
      *                          *
      *                          *
      ****************************
      @view.render()
```

while this works, i must say i don't like it. introducing an artificial delay so the client can get the channel and start listening (i tried with no delay, and the client didn't get the uuid) is dangerous, as it might still miss if the system get busier, but making it too long hurts the reactivity aspect.

if anyone has a solution in which this can be done synchronically - having the uuid returned as part of the original eventSource request - i would be more than happy to demote my solution.